# Rails - run method only after a specific attribute's JSON field is updated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to run a method in Rails only after the JSON field `search_terms` of the `settings` attribute  is updated.

The model's name is `Campaign` and this is an example of an instance's attributes:

```
Campaign.first.attributes

=> {
               "id" => 1,
             "name" => "example.com",
           "status" => "on",
        "languages" => [],
          "country" => nil,
         "settings" => {
                   "search_terms" => {
            "happy" => true,
            "sad" => true,
              "excited" => true
        },
        "keyword_refresh_intervals" => {
            "en-us" => 60,
            "ru-ru" => "0",
            "en-gb" => "0"
        }
    },
    "advertiser_id" => 1,
       "created_at" => Sun, 25 Dec 2016 10:55:47 UTC +00:00,
       "updated_at" => Tue, 28 Feb 2017 08:07:05 UTC +00:00
}
```

In the Campaign model itself I'm executing the required Job after a commit is made:

```
class Campaign < ApplicationRecord
  after_commit -> { PlacementsGeneratorJob.perform_later }
```

But I want it to be executed only after the `search_terms` value is changed in the `settings` attribute and not when the whole `settings` attribute is changed.

Is that even possible?

**EDIT:**

So for example I can check changes on the `settings` attribute:

```
Campaign.first.settings_changed?
=> true
```

But I can't do something like:

```
Campaign.first.settings["search_terms"]_changed?
SyntaxError: unexpected tFID, expecting end-of-input
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create guard method in job to check if part of attribute is changed.
To do this you can send Active Record to job (Active job using GlobalID for this now), and your new search terms.

In job you can use before perform, or around perform to do all needed logic. [Documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveJob/Callbacks/ClassMethods/around_perform)

Example

```
    class Campaign < ApplicationRecord
      after_commit -> { PlacementsGeneratorJob.perform_later self, new_search_terms } 
     .....


 class PlacementsGeneratorJob < ActiveJob::Base
  around_perform do |job, block|
    check_changes job.arguments[0], job.arguments[1]
    block.call

  end

  def perform record, new_search_terms=nil
    return if @no_chnages
     .....
  end

  private
  def check_changes record, new_search_terms
    @no_changes = true unless new_search_terms
    old_record = record.settings['search_terms']
    @no_changes = old_record==new_search_terms 

  end
 ....
 end
```

Of course this is just base example of principles. You will need to write your own logic here. Hope this helps.

Comment: doesn't work for me. got caught up several hours trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's a 'Rails way' of doing this. For a quick and simple solution, I would suggest adding a `before_save` callback to compute an MD5 value of `settings['search_terms']`, which you can store as a `Campaign`'s attribute, e.g. `search_terms_md5`. Then, when you want to check if `search_terms` have changed since last save just compare the current MD5 value with the stored one.

```
require 'digest/md5'

class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :compute_md5_of_search_terms
  after_commit -> { PlacementsGeneratorJob.perform_later }, if: 'search_terms_changed?'
  ...
  def compute_md5_of_search_terms
    search_terms_md5 = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(settings['search_terms'])
  end

  def search_terms_changed?
    Digest::MD5.hexdigest(settings['search_terms']) != search_terms_md5
  end
end
```

Comment: this is an overkill. If I'm adding a column I'd move the search_terms from settings to it's own but I don't want to.